# ffmpeg transcode video from different sizes to 4:3

Tags: ffmpeg

We have some videos that have different scale and aspect ratio and we'd like to convert them to a fix 640x480 size (4/3 ar letterbox padding if necessary). 
Two sizes are occurs very often: 853 × 480, 1280 × 720.
I made some research and tries before write this question but didn't get the expected result.

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "scale=640:480,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setdar=4/3" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

**setdar=4/3** seems to required because if I omitted the result remain the original aspect ratio.

Are there any solution for different size conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic filterchain for fitting a video in a WxH canvas is

```
"scale=iw*sar:ih,scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:-1:-1"
```

The first scale filter makes sure the video is not kept anamorphic. If you know the video is square-pixels, you can skip it. The 2nd filter fits the video in a canvas of 640x480 using the `force_original_aspect_ratio` option.

Comment: Thank you Gyan it's exactly what I was looking for!